# Trying to open a serial port. Getting error . What is causing the error?

Tags: c#, mono, serial-port

I am using mono and C# to open the ttys2 port on my  computer. I have spent lots of time trying to figure out why I cannot open my serial ports. I finally included a try catch to help figure it out. I am new to C# .. So any guidance would help.

```
Button was just pushed .... Opening Port....
Error in Opening dev/ttys2
System.IO.IOException: No such file or directory
  at System.IO.Ports.SerialPortStream.ThrowIOException () [0x00012] in 
<f8255d9ef0594d18ae2c0d97286b9a80>:0 
at System.IO.Ports.SerialPortStream..ctor (System.String portName, 
System.Int32 baudRate, System.Int32 dataBits, System.IO.Ports.Parity 
 parity, System.IO.Ports.StopBits stopBits, System.Boolean dtrEnable, 
System.Boolean rtsEnable, System.IO.Ports.Handshake handshake, 
System.Int32 readTimeout, System.Int32 writeTimeout, System.Int32 readBufferSize, System.Int32 writeBufferSize) [0x0001e] in <f8255d9ef0594d18ae2c0d97286b9a80>:0 
   at (wrapper remoting-invoke-with-check) 
    System.IO.Ports.SerialPortStream:.ctor (string,int,int,System.IO.Ports.Parity,System.IO.Ports.StopBits,bool,bool,System.IO.Ports.Handshake,int,int,int,int)
  at System.IO.Ports.SerialPort.Open () [0x00078] in 
<f8255d9ef0594d18ae2c0d97286b9a80>:0 
  at (wrapper remoting-invoke-with-check) 
System.IO.Ports.SerialPort:Open ()
  at MonoSerial.Program.Main () [0x00089] in 
 <805ba7595bb8403d9fb17ebbff143c7f>:0
```

Here is the code I wrote:

```
 Console.WriteLine("Button was just pushed .... Opening Port....");
        SerialPort Serial_tty = new SerialPort();
        string ttyname;
        ttyname = "dev/ttys2";


        Serial_tty.PortName = ttyname;            // assign the port name 
        Serial_tty.BaudRate = 9600;               // Baudrate = 9600bps
        Serial_tty.Parity   = Parity.None;        // Parity bits = none  
        Serial_tty.DataBits = 8;                  // No of Data bits = 8
        Serial_tty.StopBits = StopBits.One;       // No of Stop bits = 1
        Serial_tty.Handshake = Handshake.None;

 try
 {
    Serial_tty.Open();                 // Open the port     
    Serial_tty.Write("A");             // Write an ascii "A"
    Serial_tty.Close();                // Close port
    Console.WriteLine("\nA written to port {0}", Serial_tty.PortName);
 }
 catch(Exception e)
 {
   Console.WriteLine("Error in Opening {0}",Serial_tty.PortName);
   Console.WriteLine(e);
 }
```

Comment: Are you sure that ports are paired?

Comment: How do I check ?

Comment: Before using serial ports, you need to establish the connection between two COM ports. How did you do that? Laptops don't have serial ports. You rely on virtual application to provide you with such connection.

Comment: I have a device connected a serial cable and a USB to  serial connected to the laptop

Comment: "Laptops don't have serial ports"? That's a pretty brave contention. Not many may *ship* with them but I have my trusty old USB/Serial converter sitting in my laptop bag right now :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
ttyname = "dev/ttys2"
```

I'm pretty certain you need a leading `/` on the front of that filename, otherwise it's going to try to open the file *relative to the current directory,* such as `home/pax/dev/ttys2`.

Comment: changed it now I am getting a resource is temporarily unavailable error

Comment: @codigomonstruo, so that would be a *different* problem. This one, now that it's been confirmed as a simple typo, should probably be closed/deleted.